# Как сделать меню на питоне?

Tags: python, консоль, текст, menu

Как сделать, чтобы я мог переходить по 4-м пунктам:

1. Георгий гарас
2. Правила
3. Язык
4. Выход

- если перехожу по 1 то выбивает ищё 3 пункта 1.Орнамент 2.Биография 3.Назад
- если перехожу по 2 то выбивает Сами правила(сам впишу) и 1 пункт Назад
- если перехожу по 3 попробую сам как нибудь сделать
- и есмли перехожу по 4 то выхожу из программы
  Код:

```
from colorama import init, Fore

text1 = """
    nn  z  nn    x    nn  z  nn    x    nn  z
x   n  zzz  n   xyx   n  zzz  n   xyx   n  zz
yx  n zzizz n  xyyyx  n zzizz n  xyyyx  n zzi
yyx nzziiizzn xyyyyyx nzziiizzn xyyyyyx nzzii
 yyx nzzizzn xyy z yyx nzzizzn xyy z yyx nzzi
z yyx nzzzn xyy zzz yyx nzzzn xyy zzz yyx nzz
 yyxyx nzn xyxyy z yyxyx nzn xyxyy z yyxyx nz
yyxzxyx n xyxzxyy yyxzxyx n xyxzxyy yyxzxyx n
yxzzzxyx xyxzzzxyyyxzzzxyx xyxzzzxyyyxzzzxyx 
xxxzxxxyxyxxxzxxxyxxxzxxxyxyxxxzxxxyxxxzxxxyx"""

text2 = """
x xxx yzzz   zzzxzxyz   zyxzxzzz   zzzy xxx x
x xxx zyzz xxx  yxzxyz zyxzxy  xxx zzyz xxx x
  xxx zzyz xxx  yyxzxyzyxzxyy  xxx zyzz xxx  
x     zzzy xxx  yyyxzxxxzxyyy  xxx yzzz     x
x      xxx yyyy      zxz      yyyy xxx      x
x      xxx yyyy xxx  zxz  xxx yyyy xxx      x
x      xxx yyyy xxx  zbz  xxx yyyy xxx      x
           yyyy xxx  zbz  xxx yyyy           
x              y      b      y         xz   x
x    zx     xxx yzzz  b  zzzy xxx     xzx   x
  x  xzx    xxx zyzz  b  zzyz xxx    xzx  x  
x yx  xzx   xxx zzyz  b  zyzz xxx   xzx  xy x
x zyx  xzxz     zzzxxxxxxxzzz      xzx  xzy x
   zyx  xzxz       x  b  x        xzx  xyz   
x   zyx  xzxzzz    x  b  x    zzzxzx  xyz   x
x    zyx  xxxbbbbbbxbbbbbxbbbbbbxxx  xyz    x
x   zyx  xzxzzz    x  b  x    zzzxzx  xyz   x
   zyx  xzxz       x  b  x        xzx  xyz   
x zyx  xzxz     zzzxxxxxxxzzz      xzx  xzy x
x yx  xzx   xxx zzyz  b  zyzz xxx   xzx  xy x
  x  xzx    xxx zyzz  b  zzyz xxx    xzx  x   
x    zx     xxx yzzz  b  zzzy xxx     xzx   x
x              y      b      y         xz   x
           yyyy xxx  zbz  xxx yyyy           
x      xxx yyyy xxx  zbz  xxx yyyy xxx      x
x      xxx yyyy xxx  zxz  xxx yyyy xxx      x
       xxx yyyy     zxxxz     yyyy xxx       
x         y        zxzxzxz        y         x
x     zzzy xxx  yyyxzxxxzxyyy  xxx yzzz     x
  xxx zzyz xxx  yyxzxyzyxzxyy  xxx zyzz xxx  
x xxx zyzz xxx  yxzxyz zyxzxy  xxx zzyz xxx x
x xxx yzzz   zzzxzxyz   zyxzxzzz   zzzy xxx x"""

colors = {
    'z': Fore.RED,
    'x': Fore.BLACK,
    'y': Fore.GREEN,
    'n': Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX,
    'i': Fore.YELLOW,
    'b': Fore.BLUE
}
inputData = input("1.Георгий гарас\n2.Правила\n3.Язык\n4.Выход")


init()
print("\t\t\t\tОРНАМЕНТ №1")
for c in text1:
    print(colors.get(c, '') + c, end='')
print(Fore.WHITE)
print("\n\n\n")
print("\t\t\t\tОРНАМЕНТ №2")


for c in text2:
    print(colors.get(c, '') + c, end='')

print(Fore.WHITE)
```

Comment: вы спрашиваете по меню в консоли, зачем копипастить сюда простыни, на которые вам ответили два часа назад? оставьте только код касательно вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, к примеру:

```
def menu():
    def first():
        while True:
            ch = input('1. Биография\n2.Назад\n')
            if ch == '2':
                return
            if ch == '1':
                print('Биография Георгия.....')

    def second():
        while True:
            ch = input('1.Правила\n2.Назад\n')
            if ch == '2':
                return
            if ch == '1':
                print('Правила: ....')

    while True:       
        ch = input("1.Георгий гарас\n2.Правила\n3.Язык\n4.Выход\n")
        if ch == '4':
            return
        if ch == '1':
            first()
        elif ch == '2':
            second()

# ваш код

menu()
```

`Python 3.9`:

```
def menu():
    def first():
        while ch := input('1.Биография\n2.Назад\n') != '2':
            if ch == '1':
                print('Биография Георгия.....')

    def second():
        while ch := input('1.Правила\n2.Назад\n') != '2':
            if ch == '1':
                print('Правила: ....')

    while ch := input("1.Георгий гарас\n2.Правила\n3.Язык\n4.Выход\n") != '4':
        if ch == '1':
            first()
        elif ch == '2':
            second()
```